# Can I prevent a scheduled task to run before a certain date

Tags: scheduled-task

As in, I don't want the scheduled task to run before the 15th of every month. Even if I (or someone else) accidentely presses 'run'.

I could also write something in the code, but I don't want to recompile everytime the date needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the task, you can select the option: Allow this task to run on demand.

Disabling this, will prevent accidental runs.

[image]